# SQL Server 2005 login error

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, authentication

I am the first time user of SQL Server. I installed it on my windows 7 machine. When I tried to login to the server it gives me an error,

> *Login failed for user 'Admin-PC\Admin'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)*
>
> *Login failed - Error Number: 18456 - Severity: 14 - State: 1*

I am using windows default authentication.

Comment: If you have UAC turned on, try launching your process as admin.

Comment: http://dbaspot.com/ms-sqlserver/148806-login-failed-error-number-18456-severity-14-state-1-a.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is the 'Run As A Administrator' on windows 7. When i choose this option, i will be able to use the MSSQL server.

Answer (score 1):

This answer  is referenced from this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx)

I am reproducing the relevant portion verbatim below :-

The error message is kept fairly generic to prevent information disclosure to unauthenticated clients.  In particular, the '`State`' will always be shown to be '1' regardless of the nature of the problem.  To determine the true reason for the failure, the administrator can look in the server's error log where a corresponding entry will be written.  An example of an entry is:

```
2006-02-27 00:02:00.34 Logon     Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2006-02-27 00:02:00.34 Logon     Login failed for user '<user name>'
                                            . [CLIENT: <ip address>]
```

The key to the message is the '`State`' which the server will accurately set to reflect the source of the problem.  In the example above, State 8 indicates that the authentication failed because the user provided an incorrect password.

```
ERROR STATE  ERROR DESCRIPTION
2 and 5      Invalid userid
6            Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
7            Login disabled and password mismatch
8            Password mismatch
9            Invalid password
11 and 12    Valid login but server access failure
13           SQL Server service paused
18           Change password required
```